# Jpa profile returns empty list in REST app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to make smart REST app, which uses profiles (JDBC, JPA). JDBC method works correctly, but JPA findAll() method returns empty list.

Object class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars", schema = "carmanager")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;
    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;
    @Column(name = "maxSpeed")
    private Integer maxSpeed;
}
```

JDBC Repository:

```
@Repository
@Profile("jdbc")
public class JdbcCarRepository implements CarRepository {

     private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     public JdbcCarRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
         this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
     }


     @Override
     public List<Car> findAll() {
          return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from carmanager.cars", new CarRowMapper());
     }
     ....
}
```

JPA Repository:

```
@Repository
@Profile("jpa")
public interface JpaCarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long>, CarRepository {}
```

Shared Repository for 2 profiles:

```
@Component
public interface CarRepository {
    List<Car> findAll();
    ....
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarRepository carRepository) {
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/car")
    public List<Car> findAll(){
        return carRepository.findAll();
    }
    ....
 }
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring-project?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.profiles.active=jdbc/jpa
```

My database:

[image: My DB]

How to make Jpa method correct?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont just call it

```
private final JpaCarRepository  jpaCarRepository;
@GetMapping("/car")
public List<Car> findAll(){
    return jpaCarRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: Because i use one controller for both profiles, and this can only be done via the shared repository, and even if I access directly via jparepository it still doesn't work